# async await not waiting for resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, im my nodeJS project I have this part of my code, that is not waiting for the await call

Controller.js

```
exports.getList = async function(request, response) {
try {
    const result = await useCase.getList()
    if (result == undefined) {
        utils.unavailable(response)
    }
    else if (result == null || result.length == 0) {
        utils.respond(response, 404, errCodes.NOT_FOUND)
    }
    else utils.respond(response, 200, result)
}
catch(e) {
    utils.unavailable(response)
}}
```

This is the function on the controller, it calls the response from the useCase

UseCase.js

```
exports.getList = async function() {
return await new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(repository.getList())
})
```

Which also calls the repository

Repository.js

```
exports.getList = async function() {
MongoClient.connect(Constants.DB_URL, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return undefined
    }  
    const dbo = db.db(Constants.DB_NAME)
    dbo.collection(Constants.DB_FEATURE1_COLLECTION).find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return undefined
        }
        db.close()
        return result
    })
});
```

So, what happens is that on the controller, the result is always undefined, since result hasn't been initialized, when it should have actually waited for the response of the Promise on the UseCase. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two `return undefned`. Maybe the promise is resolving, and the resolved value is `undefined` because that's what's being returned?

Comment: Do you see any error log in the console?

Comment: no, to both, no error on the console, and the repository is actually returning the list correctly, I debugged and it goes on the rest of the function before even returning the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getList` function does not have return statement, and since it is `async` it returns a Promise that always resolves with `undefined`. I am not very familiar with `MongoClient`, but [documentation says](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html) it returns a promise if no callback is specified. So you can change your code:

```js
exports.getList = async function () {
    try {
        const db = await MongoClient.connect(Constants.DB_URL);
        const dbo = db.db(Constants.DB_NAME);
        const result = await dbo.collection(Constants.DB_FEATURE1_COLLECTION).find({}).toArray();
        db.close();
        return result
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return undefined
    }
};
```

and UseCase.js:

```js
exports.getList = function() { 
    return repository.getList(); // it returns a Promise there is no need to wrap it in async 
};
```